# Programmatically use RGBa values in fillStyle in <canvas>?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Using `<canvas>`, I want to set the RGBa value of the rectangle using a variable.

for example:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(32, 45, 21, 0.3)";
```

works fine, but using it with a variable:

```
var r_a =  0.3;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(32, 45, 21, r_a)";
```

doesn't work.

Apparently `fillStyle` only accepts a string. So how do I set a value of the rgba value using some variable instead of explicitly defining the values?

Comment: "I'm breaking any rules or guidlines here then please let me know gently and I'll keep it in mind for next time..." The one thing to learn is that it's polite to accept an answer if someone has provided the answer that you need. To the left of each answer, under the score, you should see a large question mark. Clicking on that will mark that answer as accepted, which gives both you and the person answering the question a bit of a reputation bonus.

Comment: Xmas eve 2009. You had your question answered within the hour. In 2016 you still didn't accept. Must've been a big Xmas party!

Answer (score 101):

You just need to concatenate the `r_a` variable to build the string correctly:

```
var r_a = 0.3; 
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(32, 45, 21, " + r_a + ")";
```

Comment: You could also use new HTML template strings: `cts.fillStyle = \`rgba(32, 45, 21, ${r_a})\`;`. This allows interpolation, which is what it looks like you were trying to do.

Answer (score 21):

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(32, 45, 21, "+r_a+")";
```

It is string concatenation.

Answer (score 8):

I'm very late to the party but I had a similar problem and solved it in a slightly different way that may be useful.

Since I needed to reuse the fill colours at different alpha levels, I used the JavaScript replace method:

```
colurfill = "rgba(255, 255, 0, [[opacity]])";
ctx.fillStyle = colurfill.replace("[[opacity]]", "0.5");
:
:
ctx.fillStyle = colurfill.replace("[[opacity]]", "0.75");
```

Obviously it doesn't have to be the alpha level that varies, it could be one of the other channels.

Comment: as a slight change to this, (with charset = UTF-8), 
colour = "rgba(255, 255, 0, α)"; 
colour.replace("α", 0.5); // can use a number here

Answer (score 7):

```
var r_a = 0.3
ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(32, 45, 21, ${r_a})`;
```

These are called template literals
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

The back-ticks `` are often found left of the number 1 on the keyboard on US keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and ran into your post, after reading it, I came up with a solution for myself, I'm working with the audio API and wanted a dynamic color based on a variable coming from the frequency in the sound file. Here's what I came up with and it woks for now, thought I'd post it in case it helps since I got the inspiration from your question:

```
function frameLooper(){ 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper); 
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount); 
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array); 
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
// Clear the canvas 

    bars = 100; 
        for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) { 
            bar_x = i * 3; 
            bar_width = 2; 
            bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2); 
            bar_color = i * 3;

    //fillRect( x, y, width, height ) 
    // Explanation of the parameters below 
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height); 
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100," + bar_color + "," + bar_color + ")" ; 
// Color of the bars
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let colo = "blue";
ctx.Style=`${colo}`;


let colo = 
arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
console.log(colo);
ctx.fillStyle=`${colo}`;
```

Comment: Please, read and understand the question, and also, when answering old question, the answers. The question was about RGBa values, and specifically the `a` part. An answer that totally ignores the existence of alpha channel can't be the answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Example code 
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

//This function changes a number to it's HEX equivelent (for n<=255)
function hex(n){
    let letters = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"];

    if(n>255){ n = 255;}  // Bounding parameters 0 <= n <= 255
    if(n < 0){ n = 0; }

    let a = n;    
    let b = n%16;
    a = Math.floor(a/16);
    b = Math.floor(b/16);
    a = letters[a];
    b = letters[b];
    return a+b;
}

//This function concatenates three hex values into one string preceeded by #
function hexColor(r,g,b){
    let red = hex(r);
    let blue = hex(b);
    let green = hex(g);
    return "#"+red+green+blue;
}

//This function simplifies the fillStyle/fill functions for canvas
function fill(r,g,b){
    let c = hexColor(r,g,b);
    ctx.fillStyle = c;
    ctx.fill();
}

//Just an example to show how it works
function drawBall(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);

    //EXAMPLE OF USING (R,G,B) LIKE IN p5.js
    fill(0,133,444); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).