# How to insert a number value of variable to rgba() function when I use fillStyles in HTML canvas property?

Tags: javascript, string

What's the result of rgba()function in CSS?Why is it wrapped by two quotes?
The `b` variable is a number, why there are two plus around it, and why does it also have double quotation?

```
var size = 50;
var offset = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1) {
  var b = i * 25;
  var rgba = "rgba(0, 0, " + b + ", 0.5)";
  c.fillStyle = rgba;
  c.fillRect(offset, offset, size, size);
  offset = offset + 20;
}
```

Comment: Is built-in where? What language or/and framework is this?

Comment: I think this is javascript, and this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957346/programmatically-use-rgba-values-in-fillstyle-in-canvas

Comment: the language is javascript,fillstyle is HTML canvas property and fillRect is HTML canvas fillRect() Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `var rgba = "rgba(0, 0, " + b + ", 0.5)";` the double quotes are not around `+ b +` but around `rgba(0, 0,` and `, 0.5)`, forming two fixed parts of this string expression where the value of `b` is inserted (after automatic conversion to string).

This expression builds a string like `rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5)` (when `i` is 2, leading to a `b` of 50) and stores it in the `rgba` variable.

**EDIT**
Let's insert some linebreaks for readability:

```
var rgba = "rgba(0, 0, " + 
            b + 
            ", 0.5)";
```

The expression consists of three parts that are added together: a string constant ("rgba(0, 0, "), the (number-type) variable `b` and another string constant (", 0.5)"). The result will be a string.

The `+` operator can be an [arithmetic operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) or (as is used here) a [string concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String).

Because you are adding a string and a number, you are using string concatenation (instead of arithmetic addition) and the number is converted to a string first. The result is a string where the third part of the expression is added to.

The result (`"rgba(...)"`) is assigned to `c.fillStyle`, which [interprets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors) it as a color.

Comment: b is a number,if a number convert to string,just use +b,right? if that ,why there are two plus abround it ,and also have a double quotes?

Comment: No, the number is converted to string because you add a number (`b`) to a string (`"rgba(0, 0, "`). And then you add another string (`", 0.5)"`) to that result. The `+` operator can be string concatenation or numerical addition (`1+b` would produce 51 if b was 50)